# How to get Chinese content using request lib

Tags: python

I am get a url using request lib(Python 2.7.10 64-bit\Visual Studio\Mac OS X):

```
url = 'https://www.baidu.com' 
con = requests.get(url)
result = con.content
```

but the result isn't Chinese:

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<!--STATUS OK--><html> <head><meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=Edge><meta content=always name=referrer><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=https://ss1.bdstatic.com/5eN1bjq8AAUYm2zgoY3K/r/www/cache/bdorz/baidu.min.css><title>\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xb0\xb1\xe7\x9f\xa5\xe9\x81\x93</title></head> <body link=#0000cc> <div id=wrapper> <div id=head> <div class=head_wrapper> <div class=s_form> <div class=s_form_wrapper> <div id=lg> <img hidefocus=true src=//www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png width=270 height=129> </div> <form id=form name=f action=//www.baidu.com/s class=fm> <input type=hidden name=bdorz_come value=1> <input type=hidden name=ie value=utf-8> <input type=hidden name=f value=8> <input type=hidden name=rsv_bp value=1> <input type=hidden name=rsv_idx value=1> <input type=hidden name=tn value=baidu><span class="bg s_ipt_wr"><input id=kw name=wd class=s_ipt value maxlength=255 autocomplete=off autofocus=autofocus></span><span class="bg s_btn_wr"><input type=submit id=su value=\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b class="bg s_btn" autofocus></span> </form> </div> </div> <div id=u1> <a href=http://news.baidu.com name=tj_trnews class=mnav>\xe6\x96\xb0\xe9\x97\xbb</a> <a href=https://www.hao123.com name=tj_trhao123 class=mnav>hao123</a> <a href=http://map.baidu.com name=tj_trmap class=mnav>\xe5\x9c\xb0\xe5\x9b\xbe</a> <a href=http://v.baidu.com name=tj_trvideo class=mnav>\xe8\xa7\x86\xe9\xa2\x91</a> <a href=http://tieba.baidu.com name=tj_trtieba class=mnav>\xe8\xb4\xb4\xe5\x90\xa7</a> <noscript> <a href=http://www.baidu.com/bdorz/login.gif?login&amp;tpl=mn&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.baidu.com%2f%3fbdorz_come%3d1 name=tj_login class=lb>\xe7\x99\xbb\xe5\xbd\x95</a> </noscript> <script>document.write(\'<a href="http://www.baidu.com/bdorz/login.gif?login&tpl=mn&u=\'+ encodeURIComponent(window.location.href+ (window.location.search === "" ? "?" : "&")+ "bdorz_come=1")+ \'" name="tj_login" class="lb">\xe7\x99\xbb\xe5\xbd\x95</a>\');\r\n                </script> <a href=//www.baidu.com/more/ name=tj_briicon class=bri style="display: block;">\xe6\x9b\xb4\xe5\xa4\x9a\xe4\xba\xa7\xe5\x93\x81</a> </div> </div> </div> <div id=ftCon> <div id=ftConw> <p id=lh> <a href=http://home.baidu.com>\xe5\x85\xb3\xe4\xba\x8e\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6</a> <a href=http://ir.baidu.com>About Baidu</a> </p> <p id=cp>&copy;2017&nbsp;Baidu&nbsp;<a href=http://www.baidu.com/duty/>\xe4\xbd\xbf\xe7\x94\xa8\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6\xe5\x89\x8d\xe5\xbf\x85\xe8\xaf\xbb</a>&nbsp; <a href=http://jianyi.baidu.com/ class=cp-feedback>\xe6\x84\x8f\xe8\xa7\x81\xe5\x8f\x8d\xe9\xa6\x88</a>&nbsp;\xe4\xba\xacICP\xe8\xaf\x81030173\xe5\x8f\xb7&nbsp; <img src=//www.baidu.com/img/gs.gif> </p> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html>\r\n'
```

How to let the content to be chinese?

Comment: Relevant: [python requests.get() returns improperly decoded text instead of UTF-8?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44203397)

Comment: Please don't change your question after you've received answers. If you have another problem, post a *new* question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `content` property returns bytes data, not text. You can turn it into text by decoding it:

```
result = con.content.decode('utf-8')
```

This will return [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#unicode) text.

Alternatively you can use the `text` property instead:

```
result = con.text
```

However, baidu doesn't send a correct charset header, so `con.text` will use the wrong encoding and return garbage. You can fix this by manually setting the `encoding` property though:

```
con.encoding = 'utf-8'
result = con.text
```

Comment: It still the text like this:"<a href=http://www.baidu.com/duty/>\u4f7f\u7528\u767e\u5ea6\u524d\u5fc5\u8bfb</a>"

Comment: @Dolphin Yes, that's the correct result. Try `print(result)` and python will display the unicode characters properly.

Comment: Yes, the print result contains chiese,but how to get the result using this code :if '作者' in book_item.text:

Comment: @Dolphin I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. `'作者' in book_item.text` will return False because "作者" doesn't occur anywhere on that website.

Comment: I am using chinese context to match the result,'作者' just am example to explain the output text next operation,it can be any chinese context.And now the print output is chinese but the variable of result does not contain any chinese.

Comment: @Dolphin Well, it's hard to say for sure, but I guess the problem is that your `'作者'` is a *bytes* string rather than a *unicode* string. Try `u'作者'`.

Comment: Handle the Python unicode is so......,I can't understand the meaning just seeing the \0xbalabala.I am going crazy!!!!!!!